# How to generate build files in next js

Tags: reactjs, build, next.js

I am learning basic next js. If we run npm run build create-react-app will generate a build folder index.html and bundle files. In nextjs. It doesn't create any build files. How will I deploy nextjs project on the server?

[image: .next folder]

Comment: Next usually needs a server to run, but if you want to create static pages out of your app, your could use [next export](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#static-html-export).

Comment: @Tholle static file will be same as build in create-react-app or is there any difference between them ?

Comment: The `build` script in `create-react-app` will create a production ready React SPA, but `next export` will create a bunch of static pages from your app, so it's not quite the same.

Answer (score 16):

Make sure your package.json file scripts appear as follow:

```json
"scripts": { 
    "dev": "next",         // development
    "build": "next build", // build nextapp to .next folder
    "start": "next start", // start nextjs server for .next build folder
    "prod": "next export"  // export nextjs files as bundle like in react app
}
```

Nodejs needs to be set to production first in .env or use it as below.

```bash
npm run build                     # to build the nextjs in .next folder
NODE_ENV=production npm run start # set NODE_ENV to production and start server
```

However, this will be on default port 3000. You can change the port to serve traffic direct to port 80 and 443 as `"start": "next start -p 80",` or use advanced reverse proxy like nginx to server your app to the world. I would recommend nginx because it multithreads and have cool security features you can implement.

#### Further Reading:

- [Current Deployment Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/deployment)
- [Former Deployment Docs](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/v9.1.4#production-deployment)

Answer (score 8):

there are two different files you can set your build in
1- if you used `npm run build` direct it will generate the build files in the folder called .next
2- if you want to make a custom folder to put your build in, so at first go to your next.config.js and add distDir:'build'

```
module.exports = {
distDir: 'build',
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I assume what you are referring to are **Static Exports**. In recent versions of Next.js you need to add

```
output: 'export'
```

to your **nextConfig** var in the **next.config.js** file.

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  output: 'export',
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Then you just need to run

```
npm run build
```

and this gonna generate an output folder called **out** with your static files, so you can deploy on your server without running any command.

Source: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/deploying/static-exports

Answer (score 4):

You can use `next export`:

```
npm run build
npx next export //if next not installed globally
```

But it disables API routes and instead of http://example.com/about you should use http://example.com/about.html.

using `next start`:

```
npm run build
npm run start -p 8080
```

Answer (score 2):

To build your next project, use **npm run build** &  for this to work you need to add this to your scrips in your package.json file-

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p $PORT"
  }
```

**next build** is the command which build the projects, which gives you .next folder containing all built content, which actually needs to be deployed on the server, but you will **deploy the entire project folder**, because you also need to install node modules.

Just ship your whole project to node js ready host and run

```
npm start
```

Comment: Shouldn't you set `NODE_ENV` to `production` before running `npm start` on the server?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I like to know where is the nexjs build files, and by using `yarn build` I found a hidden folder which name was `.next` and all of build stuff was there:

[image: nextjs build folder]

Answer (score 0):

I generally use the Next CLI for generating Next applications. Its very similar to create-react-app but also generates the structure for Next, following all of the best practices. This includes a Next build script:

`npm run build`

On a side note I've personally found that the Zeit hosting is an ideal platform for Next apps (they are the guys who develop Next). You can deploy your app as is with the `now` command, and they handle building etc.

Here's an example of a recent Next app I built which I am hosting on now: https://stage.comerbeber.mx

Comment: Hi what does your package.json look like? For example I'm using a NextJS project as well, and using Now as a host. However after running `npm run build` I don't have a build folder like in my older projects. So when I deploy it's this: https://moonholdings-9959xq3a2.now.sh/

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to generate the build:
1 through npm

- npm build
  2 through yarn(YARN is a package manager)
- yarn build (for this you have to add yarn to your project, you can do it by
  write `npm i yarn`)
- to start the server write `yarn dev`.
  There are many reasons for your yarn as it has many trouble shooting features and it is faster then npm package mangaer.

Answer (score -1):

First, after creating the app, **customise** the **package.json** file as your own, like-

```
 "scripts": {
     "dev": "next dev",
     "build": "next build",
     "start": "next server.js"   
}
```

then, use `yarn dev` to run your project in the server default,

http://localhost:3000/